# ListPlot3D: combine VertexColors and RegionFunction

Tags: plotting, graphics

I've found that `RegionFunction` and `VertexColors` don't work together.

Example:

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[ {x/100, y/100, Sin[2 Pi x/100] Cos[2 Pi y/100]}, {x, 
     100}, {y, 100}], 1];
colorvals = (Sqrt[2] N[Norm[#[[1 ;; 2]] - {1, 1}/2]] & /@ data);
ListPlot3D[data, VertexColors -> Hue /@ colorvals]
```

[image]

Adding `RegionFunction` suppresses the colors..

```
ListPlot3D[data,
 VertexColors -> colors, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y}] < 1]]
```

[image]

Any work-around?

My actual data is not on a regular grid, and the region is not convex, if that matters.

Edit: I should have said, my actual color data is already tabular, there is no analytic function to work with as in the example.

---

Edit: in case anyone comes across this for discrete color values, create an interpolating function:

```
int = Interpolation[Transpose[{data[[All, ;; 2]], colorvals}], 
         InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

then use `ColorFunction -> (Hue[int[#1, #2]] &)` in @paw's answer
(This will likely generate some extrapolation warnings, so use `Quiet` )

Comment: Indeed, if you look at the `InputForm[]` of the second plot, no `Hue[]` objects can be found; thus, the explicit color setting is being ignored in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ColorFunction`to get around this issue.

```
ListPlot3D[data, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y}] < 1], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[Sqrt[2] N[Norm[{x, y} - {1, 1}/2]]]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: great! I had to use an interpolating function since my data is given in tabular form (I suppose I should have said that..), but this does the job.